# Is Quorra's name a reference to anything?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

Many of the names of things/characters on the grid are references to various things/people related to computers, like Zuse after [Konrad Zuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konrad_Zuse) and Alan Bradley after [Alan Kay](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlanKayIsTron).

Is there a computer-related reference in Quorra's name that I'm missing?

Comment: Actually I think TRON is in reference to a command that some micros used to have "way back when".  You could turn tracing (displaying a list of line numbers being executed) off and on with the TRON and TROFF commands.  TRON would then be "TRace ON" - which was in line with what TRON's original purpose was - watchdogging the system, including the MCP.

Comment: cuore is italian for heart. quorra is not an Italian word and it doesn't sound like one, the combination of letters being rather atypical.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch, but how about an incorrect conjugation of [Quorum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum)?  So in that context, the character Quorra would be something like the representative of all ISOs...?

Comment: @David: Your claim is false; the history of the character is detailed with an interview with Lisberger on the DVDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name Quorra is not known to have any significance related to the computer world.

This could be explained by the fact that, according to the [TRON: Betrayal](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON:_Betrayal) comic book, ISOs pick their own names :

[image: The birth of Ophelia]